# Can't export database from Android phone

Tags: java, android, sqlite, file

I want to export my database to file. Here is my code.

```
public static void backupDatabase(Context mContext) throws IOException {
    //Open your local db as the input stream
    String DB_PATH=null;
    if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        DB_PATH = mContext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    } else {
        DB_PATH = "/data/data/" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    }
    DB_PATH=DB_PATH+"SamsungLightingApp.db";
    File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(dbFile);

    String outFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MY DB.db";
    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    //Close the streams
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    fis.close();
}
```

> When we open FileInputStream it will throw error that the file is not exist.
>   Always i am getting `FileNotFoundException`.

Answer (score 1):

run adb command to check where is your database is located.

adb shell

run-as package-name

locate the database path and check is it matching with your path from program.

Answer (score 0):

Use `context.getDatabasePath(dbfilename)` to get the File for the database.  Never assume any kind of hardcoded path.

Answer (score 0):

`context.getDatabasePath("dbfilename.db")` has been around since API 1. It would work surely if the database file exits. It would return a File.